# Using vim to replace not matching strings that occur a variable number of times

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I'm looking to use vim to extract *only* the square brackets and the number inside from a file containing the following example text:

```
13_[4]_3_[4]_[1]_5_[1]_29_[3]_4_[2]_9_[1]_6_[2]_4
14_[4]_28_[3]_4_[2]_12_[1]_8_[2]_2
[1]_[4]_15_[1]_16_[3]_4_[2]_11_[1]_16_[2]_2
9_[4]_3_[4]_3_[4]_9_[4]_4_[4]_7_[1]_12_[3]_4_[2]_9_[1]_[2]_2
14_[4]_30_[3]_4_[2]_5_[1]_19_[1]_3_[1]_8_[2]_10_[1]_4_[1]_3_[1]_2
```

So for the first example line I would like an output line that looks like:
    [4][4][1][1][3][2][1][2].

I can easily delete the square brackets with:

```
:%s/\[\d\]//g
```

but I am having real trouble trying to delete all text that doesn't match [/d]. Most vim commands that work with negation (e.g. :v) appear to only operate on the whole line rather than individual strings, and using %s with group matching:

```
:%s/\v(.*)([\d])(.*)/\2
```

also matches and deletes the square brackets.

Would someone have a suggestion to solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. You need to quote the square brackets and use something far less greedy than `.*`.

```
:%s/\v[^[]*(\[\d\])[^[]*/\1/g
```

#### Overview

Match leading text + `[` + digit + `]` + trailing text. Capturing the `[` + digit + `]`. Replace the match the capture group. Leaving only the brackets and digits.

#### Glory of details

- Using `\v` for very magic. See `:h magic`
- `[...]` is a bracketed character classes which matches any of the characters inside. e.g. `fooba[rs]` matches `foobar` and `foobas`, but not `foobaz`. See `:h /\[`. (Note Vim may call this this a collection.)
- `[^...]` is an negated bracketed character class, so matches none of the charcters inside the brackets. e.g. `fooba[^rz]` matches `foobas`, but not `foobaz` and `foobar`.
- `[^[]` - match any non-`[` character. (This looks funny)
- `[^[]*` - match are non-`[` character zero or more times. This will match the leading text we want to remove.
- `(...)` - capture group
- `\[` & `\]` represent literal `[` / `]`. We must escape to prevent a character class.
- `\d` match 1 digit.
- `[^[]*` - match trailing text to be removed
- `\1` the replacement will be our capture group aka bracketed digits.
- Use the `g` flag to do this globally or more plainly multiple times.
- Use a range of `%` to do a substitution, `:s`, over the entire file, `1,$`.

#### So why does `:%s/\v(.*)([\d])(.*)/\2` fail?

tl;dr: Your pattern doesn't match. Try `/[\d]`.

Long version:

- The first `.*` will capture too much leaving only the last portion. e.g. `[2]...`.
- `[\d]`creates a bracketed character class that matches one of the following characters: `d` or `\`
- The second `.*` suffers from the same problem as the first when using the `g` flag.
- Why not 3 capture groups? You can certainly have more capture groups, but in this case they unnecessary, so remove them.
- Missing `g` flag. This means the command will only do 1 substitution per line which will leave plenty of text.

#### General regex and substitution advice

When working with a tricky regex pattern it is often best to start with a search, `/`, instead of a substitution. This allows you to see where the matches are beforehand. You can tweak your search via `/` and pressing `<up>` or `<c-p>`. Or even better use `q/` to open the `command-line-window` so you edit your pattern like editing any text. You can also use `<c-f>` while on the command line (including `/`) to bring up the `command-line-window`.

Once you have your pattern then you want to start your substitution. Vim provides a shortcut for using the current search by using an empty pattern. e.g `:%s//\1/g`.

This technique especially combined with `set incsearch` and `set hlsearch`, means you can see your matches interactively before you do your substitutions. This technique is shown in the following [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/).

Need to learn more regex syntax? See `:h pattern`. It is a very long and dense read, but will greatly aid you in the future. I also find reading Perl's regex documentation via `perldoc perlre` to be a good place to look as well. Note: Perl's regexes are different from Vim's regexes (See `:h perl-patterns`), but Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) are very common.

#### Thoughts

You may also consider `grep -o`. e.g. `%!grep -o '\[\d\]'`.

#### More help

```
:h :s
:h range
:h magic
:h /\[
:h /\(
:h s/\1
:h /\d
:h :s_flags
:h 'hlsearch'
:h 'incsearch'
:h q/
:h command-line-window
:h :range!
```

Comment: That's really helpful. For the `[^[]` I kept seeing the second brackets as pairing, which thoroughly confused me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
:%s/\v[^[]*(%(\[\d\])?)/\1/g
```